# How to import models from Speed tree to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I create a tree model in Speed tree.
There are three materials I used in those leaves.
There are four groups of flower with three different materials.
[image: Tree models in Speed tree.]
However, I only got one material of leaves when I open this model file in Unity environment.
 [image: Some materials were loose.]

The second question is the texture mapping is on the wrong position.
It looks like the uv mapping problem.

How can I solve these two problems?

Comment: Have you tried speedtree for unity - http://www.speedtree.com/unity/ ?

Comment: Yes, I created this tree in "speedtree for unity".